# Calculating Time of Parent and Child Processes

Tags: c, time, process, pipe, parent-child

I am trying to find a way to calculate time for my parent and child processes. In particular:

1. The time prior to and after generating a child process (start and end time of parent)
2. The time at which child process begins execution (end time of child)

This is within a program where I have created multiple child processes from a parent process. The child process would transfer its child time via pipe to the parent process. I've looked into using C functions and headers with time but I am unsure how to go about getting it down to microseconds within the processes themselves rather than in the form of seconds from 1970.

This is my code so far, any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h> // for reaching unix operations
#include <time.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
pid_t main = getpid();

int N = 30;
int i;
int fd[2*N];
pid_t* children = (pid_t*)malloc(sizeof(pid_t) * N);
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    pipe(&fd[2 * i]);
    pid_t child = fork();
    if (child == 0) {
        pid_t me = getpid();
        close(fd[2 * i]);
        write(fd[2 * i + 1], write_buffer, SIZE);
        printf("I'm a child and my pid is: %d\n", me);
        sleep(1);
        // exit(4);
        return me * 2;
    }
    else if (child < 0) {
        // printf("Could not create child\n");
    }
    else {
        close(fd[2 * i + 1]);
        read(fd[2 * i], read_buffer, SIZE);
        children[i] = child;
        // printf("I have created a child and its pid %d\n", child);
    }
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: To fetch time with better than 1s precision, you'll want either `gettimeofday()` or `clock_gettime()`.

Comment: You've omitted too much necessary information.  You really need to learn about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You also need to state whether you want the CPU time used by the child processes or the 'wall clock' time.  You show the use of `read_buffer` and `write_buffer` but they're neither defined nor initialized.  You need to consider what format the start and end messages from a single PID should take.